# keyboard not respondiing after installing Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

I installed Ubuntu and made sure the keyboard was recognized at that section of the install.  At the end of the installation it asks to remove the disk and hit enter.  The keyboard does not respond and I'm stuck on that screen.  What next?

Answer (score 0):

Something in the power management scripting didn't work.  At this point Ubuntu is fully unloaded and it's safe to just push the power button to turn it off.